# Set important of message in reply - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using [Microsoft graph api Reply API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to send reply to incoming emails. Our requirement is to set importance to high for emails. However the request payload as shown below does not have any option to set the importance or other message parameters. Can someone suggest how to make a reply by changing message properties?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADA1MTAAAAqldOAAA=/reply
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "message":{  
    "toRecipients":[
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address":"samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
          "name":"Samantha Booth"
        }
      },
      {
        "emailAddress":{
          "address":"randiw@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
          "name":"Randi Welch"
        }
      }
     ]
  },
  "comment": "Samantha, Randi, would you name the group please?" 
}
```

Please note that if we use send api, then the conversation ID will get lost and outlook will not show the mail as a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you can add you parameter while replying to the mail,
[image]

You can add the any property you want to add under [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) object, you can see the property importance under message
[image]

You can try with below code
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/reply](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7Bmessage_id%7D/reply)

```
 {
        "message": {
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "address": "xyz@microsoft.com",
                        "name": "Vicky"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "importance": "high"
        },
        "comment": "adding importance high"
    }
```

[image]

Mail with high importance
[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks